# Fast selection algorithm for duplicate-heavy inputs?

Tags: algorithm, duplicates, top-n

I've familiarized myself with quickselect and median-of-medians for fast selection of the k-th element in an unsorted array. If you try hard enough, you can guarantee the worst case time complexity to lie in O(n).

My problem is a little different. I'd like to select the k-th number from an unsorted array which contains a very large amount of unpredictable duplicates. What I wonder, is whether there's an approach which is both memory and time efficient with respect to the amount of unique values `u` as opposed to the total size of the input `n`. The catch is that sometimes `u << n` and sometimes `u ~ n`.  (In practice, `u` is almost constant, while `n` fluctuates heavily.)

Bad approach 1 (excuse my python pseudocode, the problem is not related to python specifically):

```
input = ...
k = ...

m = hashmap()
for value in input:
    if value exists in m:
        m[value] = m[value] + 1
    else:
        m[value] = 1

cumulative_sum = 0
for unique_value in ordered(m):
    cumulative_sum += m[unique_value]
    if cumulative_sum > k:
        return unique_value
```

This is currently my baseline. What I don't like about it is that ordering or keeping `m` ordered using comparison takes `O(u*logu)` time.

Bad approach 2:

```
input = ...
k = ...

M = some_value
assert type(input) == integral
assert min(input) == 0
assert max(input) == M

a = array(size=M+1, default_value=0)

for value in input:
    m[value] = m[value] + 1

cumulative_sum = 0
for i in range(M+1):
    cumulative_sum += m[i]
    if cumulative_sum > k:
        return i
```

This is obviously bad, because it takes `O(M)` time and `O(M)` space as well.

Is there any good way to update quickselect (or do something else entirely) to solve the problem in `O(u)` time and `O(u)` space?

As @kcsquared noted, if the input array is given as-is, there is no way to break the `Omega(n)` time limit. Does anything change if the input is in format `[(v1, c1), (v2, c2), ..., (vn, cn)]`, where `(v, c)` corresponds to one unique value; `v` being the value and `c` being the number of its occurences in the original input?

Comment: Are you making repeated selection queries on the same array? Otherwise, you need to look at each element of the array at least once (if you don't know `u` in advance) so `Omega(n)` is unavoidable for time complexity.

Comment: @kcsquared No, only a single selection query. You're right of course. Say you actually do know `u` in advance: what if your new inputs were 2-tuples `(v, c)`, where `v` would be your value and `c` would be the amount of occurences of it in the original input. Would that change anything?

Comment: A Dutch-flag partitioning algorithm may be of some use here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem

Comment: @CiaPan Thank you for your suggestion; it might be the case that I'm missing something, but I don't think the algorithm can be used for solving this problem, since the algorithm passes the entire array (`j` and `k` meet), which makes it `T(n)`, not mentioning the fact that the input query is a value, not an index.

Comment: 1. You can't find an answer, which depends on n input values, without reading those n values. 2. _'I'd like to select the **k**-th number'_ looks like an index to me, not a value.

Comment: You can use quick select on this.  Just make your (v,c) multi-set first, then apply the quickselect algorithm.  But instead of using the partitions length to decide which to recur on, track and use the v.count sum.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Do you mean the `O(u^2)` quickselect algorithm, or the median-of-medians `O(u)` version? If it's the second one, I would greatly appreciate an answer written out, since I've tried and failed to find a way to adapt median-of-medians to frequency-counts.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I second that. ATM I'm trying to parse @btily's answer, wondering what he means by "assigning a weight to each `v` by `c`, and proceeding with quickselect".

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, exactly, I'm looking for an index, but the dutch-flag algorithm is working with a value, see the pseudocode signature `(a : array, mid : value)`. And yeah, the array is fully constructed in the memory, which takes up `O(n)` space, which I don't have.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Do I understand correctly that you'd just use the partitions on the values `v` from `(v, c)` tuples and then, after the partition is complete, you'd calculate a cumulative sum over the partitioned array, recur into the half according to whether the cumsum on the pivot is larger or smaller than `k` and just keep recurring until the subproblem size is trivial?

Comment: Yes, basically.  It’s the same as @btilly’s first solution.  You can actually calculate the sub partition sums as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For memory, yes.

Create a hash mapping values to count.  This hash will have size `O(u)`. And then you can do a quickselect giving each value a weight equal to the count.

But for time, you have to read the whole array which is `O(n)`.  Unless you are happy with an approximate answer. In which case you can take a random selection from the array, figure out a hash of approximate counts, and quickselect that.  Depending on the purpose, that may be close enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, approximations will not suffice (part of a critical pipeline). However, thank you for the answer, I think I just got how the updated quickselect would work. I'll implement it tomorrow and get back to you as soon as possible!